# Time Complexity of Algorithms (Big Oh notation)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hey just a quick question,
I've just started looking into algorithm analysis and I'm attempting to learn Big-Oh notation.

The algorithm I'm looking at contains a quicksort (of complexity O(nlog(n))) to sort a dataset, and then the algorithm that operates upon the set itself has a worst case run-time of n/10 and complexity O(n).

I believe that the overall complexity of the algorithm would just be O(n), because it's of the highest order, so it makes the complexity of the quicksort redundant. However, could someone confirm this or tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong.

Quicksort has worst case complexity O(n^2). But even if you have an O(nlogn) sort algorithm, this is still more than O(n).

Comment: Ah thank you. I posted without thinking. I saw "log(n)" and thought small, forgot to take the co-efficient into consideration.
Thanks for your help :)